# Show error page for different themes against one error

Tags: java, exception, spring-mvc

I am working on an application in J2EE, Spring mvc.

Application has two themes. If `java.lang.Exception` comes it is handled.
I configure error page in web.xml as:

```
<error-page>
     <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
     <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/uncaughtException.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Each time in any theme **uncaughtException.jsp** is displayed. I want to show different page for different themes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did the following work around in order to show different message for different exception I think this trick can help you.

I'just redirecting on exception with different message each time and show this message on the same page.

```
  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
      public ModelAndView handleMyException(Exception  exception) {
         ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:errorMessage?error="+exception.getMessage());
         return mv;
              } 

  @RequestMapping(value="/errorMessage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView handleMyExceptionOnRedirect(@RequestParamter("error") String error) {
      ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("uncaughtException");
      mv.addObject("error", error);
      return mv;
       }
```

**Update:**

You can also use `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` it might be more useful in your case:
you can just map each exception to each page and the the default page.

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException">/general/error/500</prop>
            <prop key="freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException">/general/error/500</prop>
            <prop key="NumberFormatException">/general/error/500</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="/general/error/500" />
</bean>

Update 2: I think you need to treat 404 separately.

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

Comment: Thanks for such a nice answer. This solution is controller specific. I want application specific solution to handle application level exceptions. Please help.

Comment: I was also doing so. Sure it works. Reference: http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/02/handling-errors-in-spring-framework.html

Comment: Thanks for Update 2: But I want to show different pages on 404 depending on my logic. <error-page> will show one page in all cases.